# Combining select and select union in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables

- Table A with 3 columns : `ID, NAME, VALUE 1`
- Table B with 3 columns : `ID, NAME, VALUE 2`

Table A :
ID : A1, A2
NAME: AAA, BBB
VALUE 1 : 1000,2000

Table B :
ID : B1, B2
NAME: CCC,DDD
VALUE 1 : 3000,4000

And I want to show the result like this :

ID, NAME, VALUE 1, VALUE 2
 A1  AAA      1000
 A2  BBB       2000
 A3  CCC                        3000
 A4  DDD                        4000

I have tried `union` and it works for `id, name` column. What about regular `select + union select`, is it possible ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ("SO") it may be easy to forget that we know absolutely nothing about your tables or data (and we cannot guess that detail). Please provide a **small sample of data** from each table and then the **expected result** of the wanted query.

Comment: have you tried the answer using `union all'?

Comment: I have tried union all but it give the same

Comment: I have tried union all but it give the same

Comment: I don't know how you could fail with the `union all` approach. It meets your **expected result* exactly as given!! [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52639817/2067753)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[online demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6863f/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ID] varchar(2), [NAME] varchar(3), [VALUE1] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID], [NAME], [VALUE1])
VALUES
    ('A1', 'AAA', 1000),
    ('A2', 'BBB', 2000)
;


CREATE TABLE Table2
    ([ID] varchar(2), [NAME] varchar(3), [VALUE2] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    ([ID], [NAME], [VALUE2])
VALUES
    ('B1', 'CCC', 3000),
    ('B2', 'DDD', 4000)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select id, name, value1, null as value2
from table1
union all
select id, name, null as value1, value2
from table2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6863f/1/0)**:

```
| id | name | value1 | value2 |
|----|------|--------|--------|
| A1 |  AAA |   1000 | (null) |
| A2 |  BBB |   2000 | (null) |
| B1 |  CCC | (null) |   3000 |
| B2 |  DDD | (null) |   4000 |
```

Comment: Tengkyu so much, it runs perfect

Answer (score 4):

You can use `union all`:

```
select id, name, value1, null as value2
from a
union all
select id, name, null as value1, value2
from b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Full Outer Join`

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.value1, b.value2
FROM tableA as a
FULL OUTER JOIN tableB AS b ON
a.id = b.id
```